# String.Split(",") Returns a nullpointer exception when accessing the 3rd item

Tags: java, android, string, split, filereader

My code:

```
public ArrayList<People_Attendance> attendance_reader() {
    ArrayList<People_Attendance> attendance_list = new ArrayList<People_Attendance>();
    String file_string = "";
    try {
        InputStream filestream = openFileInput("Attendance_File");
        if (filestream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(filestream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }
            file_string = stringBuilder.toString();
            String parse_array[] = file_string.split(";");///splits into individual People_Attendance items.
            String item_name; String item_number; String item_status; ///declares all the item strings

            for(String person_item : parse_array) {
                String item_parse_array[] = person_item.split(",");
                item_name = item_parse_array[0];
                item_number = item_parse_array[1];
                item_status = item_parse_array[2];

                attendance_list.add(new People_Attendance(item_name, item_number, item_status));
                ///above is an example of an initialization method, custom inside of People_Attendance class.

            }
        }
```

At the line:

```
People_Attendance item = new People_Attendance(item_name, item_number, item_status);
```

How is this initialization wrong? It gives a NullPointerException, so presumably one of my strings is null??
I have debugged and found that the error is here. I also found my reader is reading correctly, because I stuck a debug line, and got text from it. I am inclined to think I'm doing something wrong with String.Split()
After more debugging I found that I get two strings after splitting - the name and the status, but not the number for some reason... Very confused. My debugging technique:

```
Log.d("DEBUG", person_item);

String item_name = item_parse_array[0];                     
Log.d("DEBUG", item_name);
String item_number = item_parse_array[1];
Log.d("DEBUG", item_number);
String item_status = item_parse_array[2];
Log.d("DEBUG", item_status);
```

Therefore I should get the number surely??

Comment: I suggest: `String item_parse_array[] = person_item.split(","); if (item_parse_array.length != 3) LOG.i("oops: " + Arrays.toString(item_parse_array));` and see what the output is...

Comment: I have a feeling that it splits on the very last colon and your last element ends up being close to empty (maybe has a newline in it at most).

Comment: NPE means the array is null to begin with. It should have NPE'd two lines earlier.

Comment: @John The one-arg `split` throws away trailing empty tokens before creating the returned array.

Comment: Put a breakpoint here, `item_name = item_parse_array[0];` Step through with the debugger.  Examine the array.  What are it's contents?  I imagine that the string is not what you think it is.  You really should learn how to debug.  You could find this in 30 seconds.

Comment: It's going at this line:

Comment: attendance_list.add(new People_Attendance(item_name, item_number, item_status));

Comment: @John, `BufferedReader` `readLine()` will consume the newlines. The input will be a one long line containing all input. Granted, there can be input lines not shown here with problems.

Comment: @SwedishArchitect How's your `People_Attendance` constructor?

Comment: @Iaalto : public People_Attendance(String name, String number, String status){
  this.people_details.name = name;
  this.people_details.number = number;
  this.attendance_status = status;
 }

Comment: That method inside of my class

Comment: Can you please post your entire input file and your entire `People_Attendance` constructor, properly indented and including any extra newlines you may have at the end, in the question so that we can properly dissect it? It would also help if you posted notes about your attempts at debugging.

Comment: `this.people_details` in the ctor looks suspicious but do update the question instead of overloading the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code you have posted and it works fine. Only place where it could have gone wrong is reading from the file. Please put a break point at the line `file_string = stringBuilder.toString();` and check if you are getting proper value.

```
class SplitFunction{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

      String file_string = "";
      file_string = "Dan Stedman,07895 678909,INVITED;Dan Stedman,07895 678909,INVITED;Dan Stedman,07895 678909,INVITED;";
      String parse_array[] = file_string.split(";");///splits into individual People_Attendance items.
      String item_name; String item_number; String item_status; ///declares all the item strings

      for(String person_item : parse_array){
        String item_parse_array[] = person_item.split(",");
        item_name = item_parse_array[0];
        item_number = item_parse_array[1];
        item_status = item_parse_array[2];
        System.out.println(item_status);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The string returned by readLine may have had some whitespace in it

The 4th element in your parse_array has no "," in it (just " "), so person_item.split(","); returns a null array.

Your line numbers must be misaligned, because it should have crashed on `item_name = item_parse_array[0]`. (it would have been an out of bounds exception if [0] and [1] were present but [2] failed).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> People_Attendance item = new People_Attendance(item_name, item_number, item_status);
> ```
>
> How is this initialization wrong? It gives a NullPointerException, so presumably one of my strings is null??

This line will NPE only if the `People_Attendance` consructor NPEs.

If the comments are correct enough, the constructor looks like this

```
People_Attendance(String name, String number, String status) {
    this.people_details.name = name;
    this.people_details.number = number;
    this.attendance_status = status;
}
```

This will only NPE if `people_details` is `null`. Nothing to do with string splitting or null `String` references but just initializing your member variables before use.